# How to change the message on the homepage

Tags: templating, entries

More newbie stuff.

Here's my `index.html`

[image: screenshot of index.html]

and here's what Chrome is doing

[image: screenshot Chrome dev tools]

So, where is it coming from because I obviously don't want that message on the homepage?

Comment: Hi @Miksu! Can you please consider accepting michaelroper's answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 7):

that's the content of the default 'Homepage' entry, which you'll find in the Entries section of the control panel. That's what is being inserted with the `{{ entry.body }}` variable in the index.html template.